# Android: High RAM usage on loading songs in app

Tags: android, performance

I just built a music player for android. In order to show songs in app I'm using `ArrayList` to hold `Song` object. Now if the number of songs are large the `RAM` usage of app increases significantly because it is holding so many songs in `ArrayList` but Google Play does the same task with so little ram even while showing so many songs. How do they manage to show a list of more than 1000 songs and use so minimal ram?

If I run my app with only 20 songs RAM usage is around 35 MB but it increases to 85 MB when I'm loading around 800 songs.

Comment: lazy loading doesn't show glitch when scrolling fast?

Comment: no @crysis it doesnt if you implement it correctly

Comment: @ankitagrawal Can you please give an example how to implement it correctly in recycler view